# Python OPC UA call method without arguments gives error

Tags: python, methods, opc-ua, opc

I am trying to call a method with no input arguements which is as follows :
[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGFe9.png

So far I have tried this  :

```
method=client.get_node("ns=5;s=Demo.StateMachines.Program01.Reset")
parent=client.get_node("ns=5;s=Demo.StateMachines.Program01")
output=parent.call_method(method)
```

but it given me this BadNotExecutable error:

```
"The executable attribute does not allow the execution of the method."(BadNotExecutable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is telling you this method cannot be executed.

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your client, check the server configuration.